# Dependant Observable Array in Knockout JS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, ko.dependentobservable, ko.observablearray

I have started to play around with knockoutjs and do some simple binding/dependant binding.
My goal is to have 1 `<select>` list populated based on the value of another `<select>` list. Both are being loaded from an ajax call to my asp.net webservice.

So I have two `<select>` lists

```
<select id="make" data-bind="options: availableMakes, value: selectedMake, optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: 'Choose a make'"></select>
<select id="model" data-bind="options: availableModels, value: selectedModel, optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: 'Choose a model'"></select>
```

Then my javascript looks like this:

```
$(function () {

            // creating the model
            var option = function (text, value) {
                this.text = text;
                this.value = value;
            }

            // creating the view model
            var searchModel = {
                availableMakes: ko.observableArray([]),
                availableModels: ko.observableArray([]),
                selectedMake: ko.observable(),
                selectedModel: ko.observable()
            }

            // adding in a dependentObservable to update the Models based on the selected Make
            searchModel.UpdateModels = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                var theMake = searchModel.selectedMake() ? searchModel.selectedMake().text : '';
                if (theMake != '') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/data/service/auction.asmx/GetModels",
                        type: 'GET',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: '{make:"' + theMake + '"}',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var makes = (typeof data.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data.d + ')') : data.d;
                            var mappedModels = $.map(makes, function (item) {
                                return new option(item.text, item.value);
                            });
                            searchModel.availableModels(mappedModels);
                        },
                        dataType: "json"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    searchModel.availableModels([]);
                }
                return null;
            }, searchModel);

            // binding the view model
            ko.applyBindings(searchModel);

            // loading in all the makes
            $.ajax({
                url: "/data/service/auction.asmx/GetMakes",
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '',
                success: function (data) {
                    var makes = (typeof data.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data.d + ')') : data.d;
                    var mappedMakes = $.map(makes, function (item) {
                        return new option(item.text, item.value);
                    });
                    searchModel.availableMakes(mappedMakes);
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });

        });
```

Currently this works as expected, but I think that I am doing this wrong as the code looks pretty long, and I could do this without using knockoutjs in less code.
Also the way that I am loading up the `availableModels` is obviously not correct because I am using a dependentObsevable called `UpdateModels` which I added in order to load up the `availableModels` based on the value of `selectedMake().text`

I hope this makes sense and you can point out an improved version of this? Or tell me simply **How do I reload the Models based on the Make selection?**

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your code looks pretty normal.  For the `UpdateModels` dependentObservable, you can actually use a manual subscription to `selectedMake` like:

```
searchModel.selectedMake.subscribe(function (newMake) {
    if (newMake) {
        //ajax request
    }
    else {
        searchModel.availableModels([]);
    }
}, searchModel);
```

This would not change the functionality, just a more explicit way to subscribe to a single observable changing.

You could also choose to use `optionsValue: 'text'` (or 'value') in the binding and your `selectedMake` would be set to the text or value directly.

If your models were children of the make objects, then you could even bind the models to `selectedMake().models` (would need to protect against selectedMake being null, which could be done using a DO, the 1.3 control flow binding, or inline like `selectedMake() ? selectedMake().models : []`

Comment: thanks. The subscribe option was what i think i was really looking for. This allows me to track the changes of the selected make, then load up the models. I tried to add the `optionsValue` attribute, but this seems to result in my `selectedMake` always being "undefined". I like your idea of the models being children of the makes, so will maybe update my code.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ryan's answer.

Taking it a bit on a related tangent, I refactored it a bit to not use ajax and to simplify the example (you can always add that back in). But here is a fiddle that demonstrates what you are looking to do with some sample data.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/vGg2h/