# Knockout working with 2 combobox

Tags: knockout.js

Im working with 2 entities -> Type and Domaine wish both have a NumeroType.

```
// MODEL TYPE
var TypeModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.Id = ko.observable();
    this.NumeroType = ko.observable();
    this.NomType = ko.observable();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};

// MODEL DOMAINE 
var DomaineModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.Id = ko.observable();
    this.NumeroType = ko.observable();
    this.NumeroDomaine = ko.observable();
    this.NomType = ko.observable();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};
```

Im would like show all Domaine wish as the same NumeroType on my select box with knockout on change. Tried so many thing but its not working ... i'm new with knockout...

```
<select name="NumeroType" id="NumeroType" data-bind="options: Type, 
                            optionsText: 'NomType',
                            optionsValue: 'NumeroType',
                            value: NumeroType,
                            optionsCaption: '---- Type ----'">                  
                    </select>
                    <select name="NumeroDomaine" id="NumeroDomaine" data-bind="options: Domaine, 
                            optionsText: 'NomType',
                            optionsValue: 'NumeroDomaine',
                            value: NumeroDomaine,
                            optionsCaption: '---- Domaine ----'">
                    </select>
```

Comment: The problem is you can't filter one drop down based on selection from another?

Comment: Try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584918/dependant-observable-array-in-knockout-js